# Is there a way to hide the ribbon for a modal dialog popup in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, ribbon

I'm on SPO and I'm looking to hide the **s4-ribbonrow** element for the EditForm.aspx which opens as a modal dialog popup window on a wiki page (not modern)

I found several possible solutions for jQuery or CSS but they all don't seem to work in SPO.

Is there still a way to hide the ribbon or disable controls for that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit newform.aspx page and add content editor webpart and below css code to it.

```
<style>
#s4-ribbonrow{
display:none !important;}
</style>
```

Note : this will hide ribbon and you will not able to save page. To save in browser developer tool remove that css and then click save. It will work.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how to add a content editor webpart to EditForm.aspx. I found a way which is to put the snippet into <SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">. 
Do you know if there's a solution without havng to edit the .aspx? I would have to change this on hundreds of site collections.

Comment: May be You can use powershell to automate this.